# High Accuracy ML.NET Image differentiation model

Tags: machine-learning, training, image-recognition, accuracy

I have a relatively big dataset (100+GB) that has 35 categories. All of them are microscopic images with slight differences. Although ML.NET documentation itself declares that training time should be much higher, in all 3 times of my training it didn't last for more than an hour. the resulting accuracy number is 0.8 but when I test it, it usually gets 2 out of 10 images right. I would like to know the possible ways to improve my practical accuracy and get more images to their respective categories.